# Is there webservice to sell layout?

Tags: web-development, website-design

I have some old layouts, and I would like to sell them, are there any popular online auctions service?

Answer (score 2):

**Rin, guessing not, but maybe, who knows.**

**(1)** You could trying to sell them on webmaster auction sites, but normally webmasters are not the in market for site templates. Examples of webmaster auction sites would be: [forums.digitalpoint.com](http://forums.digitalpoint.com) and [marketplace.sitepoint.com](http://marketplace.sitepoint.com)

**(2)** A big template site like [monstertemplates.com](http://monstertemplates.com) likely wouldn't be interested in them either.

**(3)** Which leaves the target market for your templates with consumers looking to buy templates, which would likely rather deal with a large company. Guessing the best site might be eBay using PayPal would be the best way to reach consumers.

**Questions that are likely to be asked are:** Have any screen shots? More Info on how much you expect to make? Info on copyright of any graphics used? If the templates are standards complaint? Which browsers they work in? Etc.

Comment: Sure, but I dont want publish details here ;) Layout is preparad for small homepage, for artist or designer. I have finished html+css also, works fine on every browsers. Also, i have .psd file .

Comment: @Rin: Right, wasn't suggesting you try to sell them here, just saying people well want to see them... :-) ...you should just look at some other template sites and pull together all the info they use to sell their template.

Answer (score 2):

[themeforest](http://themeforest.net) is what your after

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out Theme Forest, They have alot of stuff there and a very active user-base.

Theme Forest Author Program:
http://themeforest.net/wiki/selling/author-selling/author-program/